# Jenkins Pipeline script -convert URL notified by slack to a clickable URL

Tags: shell, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, slack

I am trying to send a slack failure notification if the Jenkins build is a failure.

However, whenever the notification comes in slack, it is not a clickable URL. It comes as http://${MASTER_NODE}:1234/job/abc/2/

I am not able to make the master node of Jenkins dynamic, as a result, it just prints as `MASTER_NODE` and not converting to a clickable URL.

Any possible solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using this http://${MASTER_NODE}:1234/job/abc/2/,

$BUILD_URL in custom message

[click here to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ZVmn.jpg)

Comment: Aditionally, if you want to give the link a label different from the full url, try ```(<${env.BUILD_URL}|Open>)``` as pointed out on the slack notification plugin page https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/slack/